# How do I get vss sdk treeview to collapse by default?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, vssdk

How can I get a combo control of type `TreeView.ComboTreeBehaviorName` to have its nodes collapsed by default?

I've tried looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/controls/tree?view=vsts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/treeviewo?view=vsts), but it seems completely unhelpful to me.

I've also tried inspecting the types (in vss.d.ts) to see if there's a property I can set:

- I found `maxAutoExpandDropWidth` which claims that it `Specifies the max size when auto-expand drop bigger than combo`, but setting it to 0 or 1 doesn't seem to have any effect.
- I found `dropOptions?: IComboDropOptions;` but it doesn't seem to
  have any properties for expand/collapse either.
- I tried adding a property `collapsed: true` to the IComboOptions
- The signature of the `Controls.Enhancement.enhance` method seems to
  suggest that I can pass some options as part of the `type` property
  on the `IComboOptions`, but I tried that and couldn't do it because
  the `type` property wants a string, not an object.
- Setting `node.expanded = false` for all nodes before passing the tree
  to the `source` property

Here are some relevant code excerpts:

```
import * as Controls_Combos from "VSS/Controls/Combos";
import * as Controls from "VSS/Controls";
import * as TreeView from "VSS/Controls/TreeView";



 this._$areaInput = $("<input type='text' id='inputAreaPicker' />")
                .val(someValueThatDoesnotMatter)
                .bind("blur", (e) => {
                    this._updateSomeOtherField();
                    this._validate();
                });
}
```

...

```
        <Controls_Combos.Combo>Controls.Enhancement.enhance(
            Controls_Combos.Combo,
            this._$areaInput,
            <Controls_Combos.IComboOptions> {
                type: TreeView.ComboTreeBehaviorName,
                source: ConvertToTreeNodes(someItems),  // loads multi-level tree successfully
                mode: 'drop',
                allowEdit: false,
                maxAutoExpandDropWidth: 1, // seems to have no effect
                collapsed: true  // no effect
            }
        );


export function ConvertToTreeNodes(items): TreeView.TreeNode[] {
    // let _this = this;
    return $.map(items, function (item) {
        let node = new TreeView.TreeNode(item.name);
        node.id = item.id;
        if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
            node.addRange(ConvertToTreeNodes(item.children));
        }
        node.expanded = false;
        return node;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is an undocumented property called 'treeLevel':

```
<Controls_Combos.Combo>Controls.Enhancement.enhance(
            Controls_Combos.Combo,
            this._$areaInput,
            <Controls_Combos.IComboOptions> {
                type: TreeView.ComboTreeBehaviorName,
                source: ConvertToTreeNodes(someItems),
                mode: 'drop',
                allowEdit: false,
                treeLevel: 0 // collapse to first level by default

            }
        );
```

[I've requested that it be documented](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1323)